# varchar field length reported incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `varchar(800)` column that is a primary key in one table and a FK to another.

The problem is that if I do `len(field)` - it says 186. If I copy/paste the text and I check it in notepad or something, I have 198 characters

The content is this :

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGGTo8JmCWDydNA19MrL4aON-02pA&amp;url=http://creativity-online.com/news/chrysler-nokia-target-among-winners-of-teds-first-ad-contest/149189
```

Any ideas on why the length difference?

**EDIT**

You are right. I was using a web based sql manager and that tricked me.

Thank you.

Comment: Need more information. How are you inserting into the table, etc.?

Comment: Where *exactly* are you performing the `len` -- SQL Server, or elsewhere? What is the exact content of that row's column for your URL? Edit your question with a screenshot. Likely you're seeing the HTML encoding from outside the database, which invalidates the question. Try this for a demonstration: `SELECT field, LEN(field) FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 123`.

Comment: @p.campbell - You were correct about the len issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you HTML encoding the URL after you have read it from the database?

moriartyn suggested that the SQL Server `len` function would count `&amp;` as a single character, but that is not the case. However, if the actual content in the field is not HTML encoded, and it's HTML encoded when inserted in the page, that would change each `&` character into `&amp;`, which would account for the extra length.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that because there are three `&amp;` in your text, the sql server len function is counting those as just & or one character, and in notepad it is counting them as five each, that would give you twelve extra in that count.

Comment: No, that's not it. The SQL Server `len` function does not count HTML entities as single characters. There is no HTML collations. It could however be that the content doesn't actually contain the HTML entities, and that it is HTML encoded after being read from the database.

Answer (score 0):

186:

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGGTo8JmCWDydNA19MrL4aON-02pA&url=http://creativity-online.com/news/chrysler-nokia-target-among-winners-of-teds-first-ad-contest/149189
```

198:

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGGTo8JmCWDydNA19MrL4aON-02pA&amp;url=http://creativity-online.com/news/chrysler-nokia-target-among-winners-of-teds-first-ad-contest/149189
```

Note the `&amp;` and `&`: 3 of them, `&amp;` is 4 characters longer = 12

You are neither comparing equally nor comparing the same strings.

In SQL:

```
SELECT
  LEN('http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGGTo8JmCWDydNA19MrL4aON-02pA&url=http://creativity-online.com/news/chrysler-nokia-target-among-winners-of-teds-first-ad-contest/149189'),
    LEN('http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGGTo8JmCWDydNA19MrL4aON-02pA&amp;url=http://creativity-online.com/news/chrysler-nokia-target-among-winners-of-teds-first-ad-contest/149189')
```